# Filter Excluding Few Sheets in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to exclude two sheets `"Summary"` & `"Result"` instead of this on the below script `filter(sheet => sheet.getName().endsWith("2020")`

On the other hand, I tried to include `2021` like this, but that didn't work `filter(sheet => sheet.getName().endsWith(("2020","2021"))`

The full script is here:

```
    function SUMMARIZE() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const weekSheets = ss.getSheets().filter(sheet => sheet.getName().endsWith("2020"));
  const summarySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Summary");
  let weekData = weekSheets.map(weekSheet => {
    return weekSheet.getRange(2, 1, weekSheet.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();    
  }).flat();
const getUnique_ = array2d => [...new Set(array2d.flat())];
  uniqueValues = getUnique_(weekData).map(e => [e]);
 
 var header = [["Company Name"]];
      summarySheet.getRange("A1:A1").setValues(header);
      summarySheet.getRange("A2:A"+(uniqueValues.length+1)).setValues(uniqueValues); 
}
```

Update: I added sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19l_gREqX1QfDHdNIjDFhW3-DNFwNKnzFWFWKXN1PaH8/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `!includes()` to **exclude** both `Summary` and `Result` sheets.

**Replace:**

`const weekSheets = ss.getSheets().filter(sheet => sheet.getName().endsWith("2020"));`

**with:**

```
const weekSheets = ss.getSheets().filter(sheet =>!["Summary","Result"].includes(sheet.getName()));
```

**References:**

[includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: I'm getting this error Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1. on line 15, 16

Comment: You have some empty sheets in your spreadsheet file that don't have any content or have only one row and therefore `getLastRow-1` becomes 0. A row with index `0` does not exist. Either exclude these sheets also or delete them or put some content there (at least 2 rows) or adjust your logic. @Nix